# Monitor nginx response time with bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, nginx

I need to monitor nginx log file. If response time greater than a particular value, I need to send mail alerts. I used following script. But when executing in a cronjob, some logs lines are skipped. 
Expected Result: - A mail triggered when column 15 in the log is greater than 1.000ms.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
DATE1=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)
###########################################
#This section counts the number of lines appended in the logs for last 10 seconds. And the number is saved into variable "dif". By using this value, we can make avoid repetitions.
before=$(wc -l < /var/log/nginx/access.log)
sleep 10
after=$(wc -l < /var/log/nginx/access.log)
let dif=$after-$before
echo "$dif"
############################################
MS=`tail -n $dif /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{ print $15}' | grep -o '[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]' | sort -V | sort -nr | head -n1`
echo $DATE1 >> /root/scripts/analysing.log
echo $MS >> /root/scripts/analysing.log
var1=`tail -n $dif /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep -B1 "$MS"|awk 'FNR == 1 {print}' | cut -d 'I' -f 3`
echo " "
echo "Last Recorded & Nginx Highest Execution Time (Millisecond) is: $MS "
echo " "
if [ 1 -eq "$(echo "${MS} > 10.000" | bc)" ]
then
echo "Current Status: Problem!!" 
echo "Description: Nginx Request Processing Time Is High!!"
echo "Nginx request execution time is greater than 10000ms on "$DATE1" I"$var1" " | mail -s "e-Agree Nginx Crossed Normal Execution Limit" -a "From: Alerts <qaz@abc.com>" "zxcvbnm@asdfgh.com"
fi
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question repeatedly.

Comment: @JacobVlijm the other way around is better. This is a much clearer question than the original.

Comment: @Ashik what logs are missing? How did you run it from the cron file? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon you are right of course.

Comment: @terdon I have run it in every minute like:-  * * * * * /bin/bash /scripts/script.sh

Comment: As I said, please **[edit]** your question to clarify. Add that cron line and tell us i) what you expect to happen and ii) what actually happened. You just say "some logs are missing" which is not useful. What logs? From where? Does some of the script work but not the rest? Are there any errors? Do you have any logging?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using word count command.

- Stored value of `${wc -l filename}` into a file at the end of the script
- The above value is taken into a variable and used as start line number
- And current `${wc -l filename}` value as end line number

By using this logic, I avoided duplicating & skipping of lines.

And added this script into crontab to run every minute.

Comment: Please could you share your script here to help others?